# Multiprocessing and Saving Output

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to calculate squared of multiple arrays (56 with size of 487x2074) which are saved separately in txt files, and save the squared sum in a txt file . I will calculate the squared sums of these output arrays for a time span for 30 years (which means I will repeat the step for 30 times).

Now, I would like to execute these multi processes parallel and examined the multiprocessing examples and came up with an idea like below:

```
def myfunction(q,year):
    betaSquaredSum = 0
    P = 56
    workingPath = os.getcwd()
    for i in xrange(1,P):

        betaPath= os.path.join(workingPath,"beta_"+str(i)+"_"+str(year)+".txt")
        betaArray = np.loadtxt(betaPath,dtype=float)
        betaSquared = betaArray*betaArray
        betaSquaredSum += betaSquared


     result = betaSquaredSum
     np.savetxt(str(workingPath)+"\variance_"+str(year)+".txt", result,
                delimiter= " ")
     q.put(year)


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    start = time.time()
    print strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S \n", localtime())

    for year in range(1999,2010):
        q = Queue()
        p = Process(target = myfunction,args=(q,year,))
        p.start()
        p.join()


    end = time.time()
    print strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S \n", localtime())
    print("Elapsed time in seconds: " +str(end-start))
```

I couldn't find out what is wrong in my code, but it is not producing the output files.

Comment: I would look into the [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) class in the `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: What is the queue for? Also, starting the subprocess and immediately joining it will run each process sequentially, not in parallel. Otherwise there is no obvious reason as to why the variance files are not created. Are you checking in the correct directory?

Comment: I have also tried Pool but couldn't work it out too. I saw queue is used to pass the results therefore I added the queue. I am running the same script without reading file and just giving a random number to array and it writes to the directory but problem occurs during reading multiple files and calculating squared sum.

Comment: `multiprocessing` on `single CPU core` ? Bad idea ! How will be sure code is wrong/missing ?

Comment: `workingPath`is not defined, could it be the issue?

Comment: I am testing on a 4-core CPU. I cannot have the output files - the variance files doesn't created in the supposed folder.

Comment: Thanks for the catch Harry. But it was my mistake to forgot to add here. I was simplifying the path while I was writing here and seems I missed to add workingPath in the question.